# htaccess redirect not redirecting index.html page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a client project that requires a specific domain name to be redirected to another directory, while the rest of the site is a standard WordPress installation.

My redirect appears to be written properly, and is placed at the very top of the htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old_domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old_domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.new_domain\.com\/directory\/" [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that it won't redirect http://old_domain.com/index.html

Instead, it sends the user to WP's 404 page.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

After receiving an otherwise helpful suggestion, I thought some additional context would be in order.

This is a real estate project. The main WP site (new_domain.com) is for condo sales, and they have a separate external site for condo rentals.

They have a third legacy domain (old_domain.com) that they want to redirect to a portal page (new_domain.com/directory), where the user can select buy or rent, and then proceed to the appropriate site.

So, we don't want all requests to be redirected, just any that use the legacy domain.

Answer (score 1):

The following rule should work. It should redirect all requests from `www.old_domain.com` and `http://old_domain.com` to `http://www.new_domain.com/directory`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new_domain.com/directory/$1 [R=302, L]
```

Change `302` to `301` when you are sure the redirect works

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old_domian.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old_domain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new_domain.com/directory/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Perhaps some context is in order. This is a real estate project. The main WP site is for condo sales, and they have a separate external site for condo rentals. They have a third legacy domain (old_domain.com) that they want to redirect to a portal page, where the user can select buy or rent, and then proceed to the appropriate site. So, we don't want all requests to be redirected, just any that use the legacy domain. I appreciate the effort, though.  Thanks.

Comment: If you put the code into the `.htaccess` file on the `old_domain.com` it will only redirect requests from that domain.

Answer (score 0):

You must have `RewriteEngine On`. You can consolidate the two www. and non-www. tests. Don't put an [OR] after the last RewriteCond.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old_domain\.com$
```

Is new_domain.com an "add-on" to old_domain.com, so that both pass through the same .htaccess file, but with different domain names? Or are these physically separate systems, with their own .htaccess files? That is, what URLs are going to pass through this .htaccess file?

Your current code will redirect *anything* coming in on old_domain.com to `/directory/<original URI+Query String>` on new_domain.com, and tell search engines and users to update their entries and bookmarks. Is that what you want?